# Understanding Persistent Volumes vs. Persistent Volume Claims and how they bind

Tags: kubernetes

I understand that a PV is the physical storage for a k8s cluster and that a PVC is just a request for storage tied to a deployment/pod that will look at available PVs and claim one.

Where I'm confused is how/if a mount will rebind to the PV if the deployment is started up. Are there cases when, if I restart my pod, that a PVC will bind to a DIFFERENT PV? Will I lose my data that's mounted in the deployment or pod? Or does that bind happen when I deploy my PVC and then just remain static regardless of the state of the pod?

I haven't really found any documentation that spells this out so any clarification would be helpful!

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

`...PVC will bind to a DIFFERENT PV?`

To ensure your PVC always bind to the same PV, you can pre-bind the PVC/PV and the instruction is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reserving-a-persistentvolume).